# How can i use the set intersection method to figure out is a sting is a pangram?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I am supposed to write a code to determine if a string is a pangram or not. I have solved the exercise by an alternative approach but I am very interested in solving it using the intersection method.

My code does not raise errors but when tested it comes out false when it should be true. This is my code:

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    a= str1.lower().replace(" ","")
    if list(set(a).intersection(set(alphabet)))== alphabet:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Please tell me if it is possible to solve the exercise in this approach and if so where did I go wrong?

Comment: Check set against set, not list against string.

Comment: As mentioned above, use `xor` and test again two sets: `if not set(a)^set(alphabet): return True`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that . That makes so much sense!

Answer (score 0):

string.ascii_lowercase returns a string that you compare to a list.

The following code checks if all letters of the alphabet are covered by the same letter from the sentence. I use a frozenset for the alphabet as it's then an immutable value:

```py
def is_pangram(sentence, _alphabet=frozenset(string.ascii_lowercase)):
    return not ( _alphabet - set(sentence.lower()))
```

Sample uses:

```
In [51]: is_pangram("Being bounced around quickly annoyed the disheveled taxi drivers.")
Out[51]: False

In [52]: is_pangram('Glib jocks quiz nymph to vex dwarf.')
Out[52]: True

In [53]: is_pangram('Public junk dwarves quiz mighty fox.')
Out[53]: True

In [54]: is_pangram('Public junk dwarves quiz mighty foe.')
Out[54]: False

In [55]:
```